# How to create a content dialog in the center of the screen in windows phone 8.1..?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

I need to create a content dialog at the center of the screen in windows phone 8.1. (by center I mean horizontal and vertical center) By default it is created at the top of the screen.

```
Can I do this....?
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't a popup control work?
From the MSDN site: "You position the Popup by setting the HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset properties. The Popup is offset relative to its immediate parent container. A Popup is not modal, so input to the screen behind it is not blocked."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842

Answer (score 0):

set

```
  ContentDialog.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
  ContentDialog.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

or by XAML

```
  <ContentDialog .... VerticalAlignment="Center" and HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
  </ContentDialog>
```